# Trying to change the Configuration File location in RCP causing a different program to run

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP GUI application and I've been trying to redirect all files needed at run-time to a folder in the users home directory.

My issue arises when trying to move the configuration folder using the "-configuration" program argument.

[image: Program Arguments]

When I just use data it works, my app starts up normally, but when I add in the configuration argument this thing opens when I run the app instead:

[image: Wrong App]

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Comment: Hello, sorry it hasn't at all, we've tried with a totally empty target platform, it's still doing it. And it's not solved the fact that the configuration property isn't exporting to the ini file.

Comment: You cannot use a 'totally empty target platform', your code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Yeah It didn't.

Comment: ... and what happened?

Comment: As far as I can tell, having gone through all the settings and target platform config, subclipse is not part of it at all. I tried removing everything in desperation, and it took me a while to get it back running again, but I haven't solved the problem with that pop-up appearing instead of my application.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because Subclipse's default policy for usage statistics is set to 'ask'. Now that you are changing the configuration area to a location where no configuration settings are stored, Subclipse - when activated - shows this dialog.

Though Subcipse is violating Eclipse UI guidelines here, the maintainers probably won't change this any time soon.

If your RCP application does not depend on Subclipse, you should remove the respective plug-ins or features form your target platform and the problem will go away.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. We aren't including Subclipse in our product the problem occurs when running the Eclipse RCP application from our development eclipse (which does have Subclipse installed) so this means that Subclipse'is trying to access configuration files of the product we are running from that doesn't even include it?

Comment: if we export the application and manually change the config.ini file it works though so is there a way to get around this in development besides removing the program args from the run configuration manually?

Comment: Yes, remove Subclipse from your target platform if it is not required by your application.

Comment: Sorry, what is my target platform? It is required by my Eclipse dev environment, and it's not in my dependencies for thh RCP Application.

Also it doesn't actually appear to be exporting the property to the ini file, it appears as it it's deliberately ignoring it, since it exports the "user" and "data" properties just not the "configuration" one.

Comment: A target platform defines the dependencies of your RCP application. Try www.google.com: 'eclipse target platform'.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found and removed subclipse from the target platform. This didn't solve the problem though I understand this is definitely along the right lines.

Comment: If the dialog still appears then you haven't (fully) removed Subclipse from your target platform. Note that you need to set your target platform as the _Current Target Platform_.